# How to connect to reverse proxy directly when it’s running in network_mode: service:wireguard

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, wireguard

I have a server running in my home network with wireguard as a client and nginx as a reverse proxy in `network_mode: service:wireguard`. This server is connected to vps with wireguard server.

When I'm connected to wireguard server I can connect to reverse proxy without any issue.

But when I try to connect to reverse proxy directly from local network, not via wireguard, connection times out.

This is my home server docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules 
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
      - 80:80
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped

  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    network_mode: service:wireguard
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: 'my-network'
```

My guess is that I have to create some `iptables` rule because when i scan host with `nmap` I get

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   filtered http
...
```

Also there is a rule in `iptables` already but it isn't enough:

```
iptables -S | grep 80
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i br-<id> -o br-<id> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

172.18.0.4 is an ip addres of wireguard container in `my-network`